# How to limit access to vocabulary term by role?

Tags: 8, users, taxonomy-terms, hooks

We have two roles: `Reviewer` and `Editor` along with two content types: `Basic` and `Article`. We have a couple vocabulary terms and taxonomy fields on each content type. Currently only users with `Administer vocabularies and terms` and `Use the administration pages and help` can edit those `vocabulary` terms, but they have access to `add/edit/delete` all Vocabulary terms (something we don't want).

**How can we selectively allow only users with `Editor` role to be able to `add/edit/delete` any values in just the `Tag` vocabulary term?**

**Basic Content Type:**

Fields:

1. Category (field_category) -> Taxonomy term field -> linked to `Category` vocabulary
2. Title
3. Description

**Article Content Type:**

Fields:

1. Article Tags (field_article_tags) -> Taxonomy term field -> linked to `Tags` vocabulary
2. Title
3. Description

**Desired outcome:**

1. Users with `Reviewer` role cannot access anything other than the nodes. (this is already done)
2. Users with `Editor` role should be able to access only the `admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/tags/overview` page (`Tags overview page`)
3. While on the `Tags Overview page`, users with `Editor` role should only be able to access that link and no other admin pages.
4. While on the `Tags Overview page`, users with `Editor` role should only be able to `add/edit/delete` any terms in the `Tags vocabulary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [taxonomy_access_fix](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access_fix)? It allows you to manage permission for each vocabulary for each role.

Comment: yes that did the work. I basically enabled that module, set the permissions, and i was able to limit the admin pages to just the taxonomy terms.